# Getting this 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting error at the start of my Spring Boot application.

I don't have access to the Spring Boot Main class as this is present in an external dependency.

I am trying to add a spring batch which is external to my spring  project.

I tried to disable this via this property `spring.data.cassandra.repositories.enabled=false`.

However, this didn't help. It's not a Spring Boot application.

**Error Logs:**

```
2023-10-20T09:44:48.481-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Bean jobRegistry already defined in the application context, skipping the registration of a jobRegistry
2023-10-20T09:44:48.482-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Finished Spring Batch infrastructure beans configuration in 3 ms.
2023-10-20T09:44:48.907-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-20T09:44:48.963-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51 ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
2023-10-20T09:44:48.968-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-20T09:44:48.982-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 Cassandra repository interfaces.
2023-10-20T09:44:49.658-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'apiCallContext' of type [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:49.659-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'apiCallContext' of type [com..api.ApiCallContext$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:49.695-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'correlationId' of type [com..api.CorrelationId] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:49.717-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'encryptionLogic' of type [com..api.crypto.EncryptionLogic] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:49.722-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'BatchApiCallContext' of type [com..batch.BatchApiCallContext] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:49.723-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'BatchConfigurer' of type [com..batch.BatchConfigurer$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:49.732-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-10-20T09:44:50.928-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] c..api.cache.CacheConfigurer   : using heap memory for caching
2023-10-20T09:44:52.497-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] c..batch.BatchConfigurer    : disabling scheduled task execution
2023-10-20T09:44:53.108-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-10-20T09:44:53.675-05:00  INFO 1052 --- [     s0-admin-0] c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-10-20T09:44:53.860-05:00  WARN 1052 --- [     s0-admin-1] c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection    : [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2bcf1e77), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException))
2023-10-20T09:44:55.951-05:00  WARN 1052 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception with message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2bcf1e77): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
2023-10-20T09:44:58.040-05:00  WARN 1052 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.p.m.PropertiesMigrationListener  : 

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception with message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2bcf1e77): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:150)
    at com..batch.BatchLauncher.main(BatchLauncher.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception with message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2bcf1e77): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception with message: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2bcf1e77): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2bcf1e77): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException.copy(AllNodesFailedException.java:141)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraSession(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.fail(ProtocolInitHandler.java:356)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.writeListener(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:87)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:185)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.send(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:76)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.send(ProtocolInitHandler.java:193)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler.onRealConnect(ProtocolInitHandler.java:124)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ConnectInitHandler.lambda$connect$0(ConnectInitHandler.java:57)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Suppressed: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9042
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown Source)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am using the following code below to start the application:

```
var context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).profiles("batch")
                .run(args);
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1:9042 is not accessible. This is not a spring problem.

Comment: Thanks Anish, Are you sure? I thought it's looking for a bean

Comment: Is there a way I can disable this to access

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the `CassandraAutoConfiguration` class completely to disable.

Try this:

```
var context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .properties("spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration")
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).profiles("batch")
                .run(args);
```

See if this works.

Comment: My mistake, my application is not a spring boot application

Comment: @saurabhkumar Please edit your question. Question is unclear.

Comment: @saurabhkumar Does this helps now?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: @saurabhkumar Let me try to reproduce om my end. Tomorrow I will update you.

Comment: @saurabhkumar I have tested on my local. it's working. I don't know what have you done.

Comment: yes it worked, but this is external project which i cant edit, is there anything we can do in parent project?

Comment: @saurabhkumar I'm confused at this moment. How are you accessing the external project in the parent project?

Comment: @saurabhkumar Please edit the question to add more details.